# React Hooks - where to put the logic that process passed props only once?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Sometimes a component needs to process passed props and save in its `state`. Since the processing can be heavy it's good to be done just once. Before hooks, it's typically done in `constructor` or `componentDidMount`.

Now coming into hooks, it can be achieved with `useEffect`, passing `[]` as the second parameter to run only once but I feel it's not the best place - what we're doing is processing props and save in state, which is not a **Side Effect**. From the docs: "Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects." Don't think pre-process belongs any of these.

So where's the best place to do it with hooks?

Comment: Why do you need to change the state depending on passed props? That'll end up in a bunch of re-renders.

Don't stop the data flow: https://overreacted.io/writing-resilient-components/#principle-1-dont-stop-the-data-flow

Comment: Why do you feel is not the best place? That's exactly where you're supposed to do it...

Comment: @GiorgioZanni `useEffect` is for side effects. From the docs: "Data fetching, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects." Don't think pre-process belongs any of these...

Comment: @AryanJ-NYC I'm not changing the state, in fact the passed props never change. It's just the props are like raw data, need to do some heavy pre-process before I can use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react';

const someExpensiveFunction = (a, b) => {
  // expensive stuff happens here
}

const someFunctionalComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
  const someVariableDependentOnProps = useMemo(() => someExpensiveFunction(prop1, prop2), [prop1, prop2]);
  return <div>{someVariableDependentOnProps}</div>
}
```

According to the docs:

> useMemo will only recompute the memoized value when one of the dependencies has changed. This optimization helps to avoid expensive calculations on every render.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: The calculation can be heavy, thus I want to compute only once and save in state as to improve performance. Does your solution avoid re-calculation?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was that heavy a computation. Updated my answer.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks heaps!